# Strange website behaviour after refresh

Tags: forms, browser

There's some strange behaviour on my website and I don't know how to fix it.

An important fact to start with: When i click on the address bar and hit enter the website is loaded very well BUT when i refresh it with F5 the nightmares happen. For example I use this jQuery script for centering a div:

```
jQuery.fn.center = function(parent) {
    if (parent) {
        parent = this.parent();
    } else {
        parent = window;
    }
    this.css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "top": ((($(parent).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollTop() + "px"),
        "left": ((($(parent).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollLeft() + "px")
    });
return this;
}
```

and after refresh the div disappears. I found out that it's because it's "top" attribute is assigned in a very strange way. After first entrance it's ok (it's centered) after second refresh its "top" attribute was set to 900px and after the third refresh it was 1100px.

The other thing is that I use this calendar script on my website: http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/ . I just assign it to block and everything works fine but after hitting F5 sometimes it gets doubled (double calendar is shown) and things like this. I thought it might happens because I use a form on the website and some javascript to handle it (modern browsers remember inputs' values after refresh) so I set autcomplete="off" on the whole form. Didn't fix the problem. What might be the reason of this?

Comment: are you doing all your scripting after document ready has fired? if not, that might be the problem, because on the first page load your brwoser retrieves all images scripts etc needed, on the second they might already be cached, therefore the behaviour could change!

Answer (score 1):

How do you implemented the call of the functions ? Evrything after "doucment ready" ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // javascript code here
});
```

Comment: All the JS code is right before the closing </body> tag AND in $(document).ready() function (except registering new functions)

Comment: I just noticed that ctrl + F5 instead of only F5 helps. What is the diffirence between these two?

Comment: Alright... how can I force the browser to clear the cache every time then?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I just found out some clue.

Ctrl + F5 helps and since it's about clearing the cache it might be it. But I STILL DON'T KNOW why this happens because when I look in the headers I see this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 12 Jul 2013 09:03:12 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.3 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1c PHP/5.4.7
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.7
**Cache-Control: no-cache**
X-Debug-Token: a4c0e3
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

So it looks like Cache shouldn't work? Why does it then?